# represent and stylize xml code in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

Showing XML code in an HTML page could be difficult.
XML tags will be recognized as HTML tags, so they will be not showed as they should.
Escaping the angular brackets <> works, but then the xml code will be showed all in black,  difficult to read. Is there a way to stylize XML code in an HTML page, as I would read it in an XML editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my **javascript** function  that changes style to xml-key-words!! 
(unfortunately it doesn't indent xml)
It accepts plain XML text as input, and return HTML styled code, with xml as text, coloring 
XML keywords with different colors as in an editor.

```
function stylizeXML(xml)
{
    xml = xml.replace(/>/g,"&gt");
    xml = xml.replace(/</g,"&lt");
    xml = xml.replace(/\&gt\&lt/g, "&gt <br> &lt");  //  ><   becomes   > <br> <


   var greens=xml.match(/<(\S+\s+)+[\S]+\=\"[^>]+>/g); //  ...=
    for (i=0; i<greens.length; i++)
        {
         greens=xml.match(/\s+\S+\=\"/g);
         for (i=0; i<greens.length; i++)
            {
             green = greens[i];
             green = green.replace(/\=\"/g, '=</span>"');
             attributes = green.match(/\s+\S+\=<\/span>\"/g);
                     for(j=0; j<attributes.length; j++)
                           {
                            attribute2 = "<span class='color_green'>"+attributes[j];
                            green = green.replace(attributes[j], attribute2);
                           }
             xml = xml.replace(greens[i],  green);
            }

        }


    var blues=xml.match(/\&lt(.*?)\&gt/g); // < ... >
    for (i=0; i<blues.length; i++)
        {
         blue = blues[i];
         blue = blue.replace("&lt/","");
         blue = blue.replace("&lt","");
         blue = blue.replace("&gt","");
         if (blues[i].match(/^\&lt\//))
             //   </ ... >
             {xml = xml.replace(blues[i],      "<span class='color_orange'>&lt/</span><span class='color_blue'>"+blue+"</span><span class='color_orange'>&gt</span>");} // </
         else
             //   < ... >
             {xml = xml.replace(blues[i],      "<span class='color_orange'>&lt</span><span class='color_blue'>"+blue+"</span><span class='color_orange'>&gt</span>");}  

        }

    var reds=xml.match(/\=<\/span>(\s*)\"(.*?)\"/g); //  ="..."
    for (i=0; i<reds.length; i++)
        {
         red = reds[i];
         red = red.replace("=</span>","");
         xml = xml.replace(reds[i], "=</span><span class='color_red'>"+red+"</span>");
        }


    return xml;

}
```

here's the CSS associated:

```
<style type="text/css">
.color_orange
    {color :rgb(255,96,24);}

.color_blue
    {color :blue;}

.color_red
    {color :rgb(234, 49, 176);}

.color_green    
     {color : rgb(72,150,163);}
</style>
```